# iOS 8 edit Apple's default keyboard?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am currently trying to make a custom keyboard now that Apple is opening up the keyboard to developers. I used the information in the developer website and it showed my how to make my own keyboard from scratch. However I was wondering if there was some way to bring up the stock default keyboard in xcode and edit that version. It sure would make things a lot easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn't do this because whenever the stock keyboard is called, Apple replaces it with your custom keyboard... if you custom keyboard is the stock keyboard then that would show and replace itself with itself over and over in an infinite loop... Apple of course prevents this from happening and just crashes the keyboard which then launches the actual stock keyboard without your custom recursion loop.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Keyboard extensions replace the builtin iOS keyboard entirely when active.